# Java: как из метода одного класса, передать строку в метод другого класса?

Tags: java

Всем привет! У меня есть два класса. Хочу из метода одного класса отдать стрингу методу другого. Бился со String, this., Static, выносил из класса. Самостоятельно - не вышло. Научите, пожалуйста, как сделать красиво. ;)

Первый класс:

```
public class ClassNameOne {

    NavigationUserSteps navigationUserSteps;

    public void methodNameOne() {
        navigationUserSteps.userIsOnARandomCatalogPage(Вот здесь хочу увидеть два слова: "home page");
    }
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class NavigationUserSteps {
    public void userIsOnARandomCatalogPage() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        String randomWebsitePageURL = "value before if";
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (day == 21) {randomWebsitePageURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";} //home page - те самые два слова, который хочу забросить в первый класс
        if (day == 31) {randomWebsitePageURL = "http://www.gmail.com/404errorpagetest";} //404 error page
        getDriver().navigate().to(randomWebsitePageURL);
    }
}
```

Первый способ решения нашёл вот такой:
Первый класс:

```
public class ClassNameOne {

    NavigationUserSteps navigationUserSteps;

    public void methodOne() {
        String page = navigationUserSteps.userIsOnARandomCatalogPage();
        navigationUserSteps.paramPam(page);
    }
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class NavigationUserSteps {
    public void paramPam(String kotik){}

    public String userIsOnARandomCatalogPage() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        String randomWebSitePageURL = "value before if";
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (day == 21) {randomWebsitePageURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";} //home page - те самые два слова, который хочу забросить в первый класс
        if (day == 31) {randomWebsitePageURL = "http://www.gmail.com/404errorpagetest";} //404 error page
        getDriver().navigate().to(randomWebsitePageURL);
        return randomWebSitePageURL; 
    }
}
```

По итогу сделал вот так: вынес выбор даты в один метод. закончил его ретурном. другой метод делает всё нужное и использует значение, которое возвращает первый. тоже туповато. Но работает красивше  ;)
Первый класс:

```
public class ClassNameOne {
    NavigationUserSteps navigationUserSteps;

    public void methodNameOne() {
        navigationUserSteps.userIsOnARandomCatalogPage(navigationUserSteps
            .selectCatalogUrlAccordingToCurrentDate());
    }
}
```

Второй класс:

```
public class NavigationUserSteps {
    public void userIsOnARandomCatalogPage(String lubayaDich){
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
        getDriver().navigate().to(lubayaDich);
        homePage.closeUiDialogWindow();
    }

    public String selectCatalogUrlAccordingToCurrentDate() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        String randomWebSitePageURL = "value before if";
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (day == 1) {randomWebSitePageURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";} //home page
        if (day == 2) {randomWebSitePageURL = "http://www.gmail.com/search/?Ntt=bubble";} //search page
        return randomWebSitePageURL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы первый класс получил данные из второго класса? Не пойму смысл написанного `вот здесь хочу увидеть два слова`.

Comment: Получается так. Это счастье нужно для фреймворка Serenity. Он выведет мне в отчёт значение в скобках. Этого добиваюсь. Пытаюсь победить через return.

Comment: Тоесть вы хотите отправить методу строку и получить от него что-что? Что? Можно по подробнее?

Comment: Смог реализовать через ещё один метод.
Изменил метод второго класса с войд на стринг:
public String userIsOnARandomCatalogPage() {...}
закончил его вот так:
return randomWebsitePageURL;
в первом классе чуть поменял.
String page = navigationUserSteps.userIsOnARandomCatalogPage();
и пришлось добавить отдельный метод, который выглядит вот так:
 navigationUserSteps.paramPam(page);

Comment: Посмотрите ответ.. Оказывается вы уже все сами поняли.

Answer (score 1):

1) Сделать метод `userIsOnARandomCatalogPage` статичным. Тогда можно будет сделать так

```
 NavigationUserSteps.userIsOnARandomCatalogPage();
```

2) Но раз уже вы создали

```
NavigationUserSteps navigationUserSteps;
```

То, будьте добры инициализируйте её, перед тем, как вызывать у этого класса методы

```
navivationUserSteps = new NavigationUserSteps();
```

Если вы хотите чтобы метод что-то возвращал, то нужно наверное лучше взяться за основы. Ну да ладно. Допустим вы хотите вернуть строку.

**Метод будет доступен всем классам** - `public`

**Метод будет возвращать строку** - `String`

**Метод будет называться** - `userIsOnARandomCatalogPage`

Получаем

```
public String userIsOnARandomCatalogPage () {
String homepage = "";
if(a>b) homepage = "a";
else homepage = "b";
//бла-бла-бла :D ваша логика
return homepage; //возвращаем результат 
}
```

Итог. Метод будет возвращать строку в зависимости от вашей логики. Чтобы получить эту возвращаемую строку в первом классе необходимо инициализировать переменную типа `String` возвращаемой строкой из метода второго класса.

```
public class ClassNameOne {

NavigationUserSteps navigationUserSteps;

public void methodNameOne() {
navigationUserSteps = new NavigationUserSteps();
String homepage = navigationUserSteps.userIsOnARandomCatalogPage();
System.out.println(homepage);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

А лучше просто сделай так:

```
public class ClassNameOne {

NavigationUserSteps navigationUserSteps = new NavigationUserSteps();

public void methodNameOne() {
    String message = navigationUserSteps.userIsOnARandomCatalogPage();
    //теперь что-то делайте с сообщением
 }
```

}